# How to include AQtime profiler to Qt creator?

Tags: qt-creator, aqtime

Okay i get AQtime and what next? Really i can't find anything about this in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AQtime does not integrate to Qt Creator. But you can profile a compiled application if it has debug information as a standalone project without any problems. Refer to the [AQtime documentation](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/43079/).